# Incorrect jquery accordion menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There is this [website](http://partssystem.ru/)

On the home page menu on the left shows-up normally (collapsed). And on this [page](http://partssystem.ru/shop/personal/info.html). It is fully expanded. Question, why is this happening and how to fix it?

Comment: without the code we unfortunatelly can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer. From the browser error console.
None of your JavaScript is getting loaded, as the paths specified are probably incorrect.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://partssystem.ru/shop/css/colorbox.css
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://partssystem.ru/shop/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://partssystem.ru/shop/js/menu-collapsed.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://partssystem.ru/shop/js/mootools.js
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://partssystem.ru/shop/js/jquery.colorbox.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready'
```

Comment: `http://partssystem.ru/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is the correct path where it exists. You have specified `http://partssystem.ru/shop/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` in that broken page.